# índice do valor - como retornar a posição de um valor que se encontra na array (começando em 0 )

Tags: javascript, array

preciso de uma ajuda! preciso implementar uma função que recebe uma array  e um valor e retorna a posição que esse valor se encontra na array?
tentei fazer assim!

porem preciso fazer também um retorno "0" ao invés do "2"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seu código está sempre procurando o valor 30. E sempre do mesmo array (scores). As variáveis 'array' e 'valor' são as que você deve usar no seu código para passar no teste.

substitua:

```
let posicao = scores.indexOf(30);
```

por:

```
let posicao = array.indexOf(valor);
```

Comment: shooooow, deu certinho, muito obrigado meu parceiro.. :)